# Error when getting contacts informations of contacts with pictures in 4.4.3

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-4.4-kitkat, searchview

I'm trying to add a searchview to my app to let users search for contacts.

I followed Jacek Milewski's tutorial (http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/android-searchview-tutorial-edittext-with-phone-contacts-search-and-autosuggestion/) and everything seams fine on most Android devices but on Android version 4.4.3 and 4.4.2 (I just tried my app on a non-updated Nexus 10 and while it works on 4.4.2 it doesn't on 4.4.3).

For every contact with a picture I get an error from the adapter:

```
09-19 17:40:03.455  29454-29454/myapp W/SuggestionsAdapter﹕ Search suggestions cursor threw exception.
    java.lang.SecurityException: com.android.providers.contacts from uid 10491 not allowed to perform READ_CONTACTS
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:148)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:682)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.getDrawable(SuggestionsAdapter.java:572)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.getDrawableFromResourceValue(SuggestionsAdapter.java:543)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.getIcon1(SuggestionsAdapter.java:399)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.bindView(SuggestionsAdapter.java:345)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.getView(SuggestionsAdapter.java:483)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1585)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5143)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4254)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the application it looks like that :
[image: Java.lan.SecurityException]

I made a github so that you can try it for yourselves : https://github.com/slyslayer/ReadContactsError/

I think that's an error in 4.4.3 but if you have any ideas on what could be the issue I'l all ears :)

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem on a 5.1.1 device. Did you have any luck finding a solution @Giom?